# I got "Fail to connect to camera service", So I can't use Camera Hardware

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am new on xamarin android.
Then I tried to access camera and display camera view stream on the textureview.
so I followed this guide, but I debug project then there is an error "Fail to connect to camera service" although I added  at my AndroidManifest.xml.

This is my Activity.cs code

```
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
    {
        Camera _camera;
        TextureView _textureView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            _textureView = new TextureView(this);
            _textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;

            SetContentView(_textureView);
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int w, int h)
        {
            _camera = Camera.Open();

            _textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);

            try
            {
                _camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
                _camera.StartPreview();

            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            _camera.StopPreview();
            _camera.Release();

            return true;
        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Size Changed");
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Texture Updated");
        }
    }
```

The error occur at 'OnSurfaceTextureAvailable' method's _camera = Camera.Open().

Thank you

Comment: I get dozens of hits on that error message - have you read through them and tried their suggested solutions?

Comment: I just followed https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/other_ux/textureview/display_a_stream_from_the_camera    this guide. in my case "Camera is obsoleted in this android platform" , but there were no suggestions and solutions. I could find only 3years ago guides.

Comment: Camera API is deprecated, use Camera2 intead

Comment: @Jason Isn't Camera API native to Android? Without knowing Xamarin, I would have expected this to be handled (and "abstracted away") by Xamarin?

Comment: Camera and camera2 are native Android APIs, Xamarin just provides wrappers for them.  See note here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera

Comment: @Jason Thanks a lot! Will take a look.

Comment: I don't want to use Camera2. It's so unkind and unhelpful for me. Too long code for me. I followed example just 50lines but It is 1000lines all files. I can't  do this. So I want to use Camera. not Camera2. How can i??

Comment: You could download the code sample on the link to test. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/ice-cream-sandwich It worked well on first time. I would keep on testing.

Answer (score 0):

i create a new project xamarin native android and test this code, and work for me on Android 10:

```
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
    {
        Camera _camera;
        TextureView _textureView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

            _textureView = new TextureView(this);
            _textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
            SetContentView(_textureView);

        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            if (Camera.NumberOfCameras == 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "This app requires a camera", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                return;
            }
            _camera = Camera.Open();
            if (_camera == null)
                _camera = Camera.Open(0);
            var previewSize = _camera.GetParameters().PreviewSize;
            _textureView.LayoutParameters =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height, GravityFlags.Center);
            try
            {
                _camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
                _camera.StartPreview();
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            // this is the sort of thing TextureView enables  
            _textureView.Rotation = 45.0f;
            _textureView.Alpha = 0.5f;
        }
        public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            _camera.StopPreview();
            _camera.Release();
            return true;
        }
        public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            // camera takes care of this  
        }
        public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(Android.Graphics.SurfaceTexture surface) { }

    }
```

and then opening the properties options, select Android Manifest-->Required Permissions-->check CAMERA

i think you have permission problem, if you have android 6 or later you need go to app manager in your device and allow camera permission or set request permission programmatically, for example:

```
int requestPermissions;
string cameraPermission = Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera;

if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, cameraPermission) == (int)Permission.Granted)) {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { cameraPermission, }, requestPermissions);
}
```

and plz using this namespace in your MainActivity:

```
//namespace  
using Android.Hardware;
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me "Fail to connect to camera service" error is runtime error in _camera.Open().

Comment: what is your device?, (if you want, send your zip file code to my email, i'll check your code, and tell you the problem)

Comment: I debug my program with my phone. My phone is gallaxy s7. May I send my code to you..?? Thank you

Comment: I solved it to get permission when runtime. Thank you so much